# Target platform with multiple Eclipse releases - Which version will Tycho use?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho, target-platform

From the site https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform, I infer the following:

- If the 'repositories' section contains a p2 repository, everything inside that repository is automatically considered part of the target platform as far as Tycho is concerned.
- If a target definition file is referenced, everything inside that target definition file is considered part of the target platform as far as tycho is concerned.

Let's say that I have a repository under 'repositories' that points to http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo like in the example. Furthermore, I declare a target definition file that points to http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios instead.

In Eclipse, developers then use the target definition file as the target platform. For dependencies in individual plug-in projects no version is defined, since the versions of the bundles are already defined by the target definition file.

The question: Will Tycho build using Indigo or Helios versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *target platform* will contain both content from Indigo and Helios. Quoting the [Target Platform wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#Effective_content_of_the_target_platform):

> In case multiple target platform configuration approaches are combined, the target platform contains the union of the content defined through each approach.

So for the *dependency resolution*, Tycho could either use Indigo bundles, or Helios bundles, or a mixture of these.

The resolution is based on the p2 planner which finds a valid solution to satisfy the requirements. In case there are multiple solutions, the p2 planner has a preference towards later bundle versions and a small set of transitive dependencies. These preferences often contradict each other, e.g. when a later version of a bundle has a larger set of transitive dependencies. So in general it is hard to predict which versions are picked in such a case.

So, if you need to know what your bundles are compiled against, use a target platform which appropriately restricts the available versions.